# Colored frame for the framed environment

Tags: color, framed

I'm using the `framed` environement to put a text in a framed box. I'm using it because I like its formating more than `fbox`. Now I would like to color the frame's border and I didn't find anything on the net to do that.

How should I proceed?

Comment: By colouring the frame you mean the border or the background or both?

Comment: Just the border

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `mdframed` package?

Comment: You could also try the [tcolorbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Comment: @ArTourter I'll try it and give a feedback

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the `mdframed` package allows you to obtain a colored frame in an easy way through the `linecolor=<color>` option. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue]
\lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}\medskip
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red]
\lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}\medskip
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=green]
\lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution using the `framed` package is also easy to achieve. You can define a new environment to give a color to the frame; in the following example, I defined the `cframed` environment to draw a colored frame around the text. The new environment simply defines `\FrameCommand` to use a `\fcolorbox`; the default frame color is blue and can be changed using an optional argument for the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{cframed}[1][blue]
  {\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\fcolorbox{#1}{white}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
  {\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}

\begin{cframed}
\lipsum[4]
\end{cframed}
\begin{cframed}[red]
\lipsum[4]
\end{cframed}
\begin{cframed}[green]
\lipsum[4]
\end{cframed}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \color{#1} \fbox}`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution is to be the closest to my question. So I'll accept it

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: but your suggestion will change the color of both the frame and the contents.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I tried the second option you suggested and it changed the foreground color.

Comment: @JosephElcid I don't understand your comment; I added an image of the result of processing my example code and it doen't change the foreground color. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, inside the frame, everything is as expected, but everything after the frame had changed color to the box color. You can add some text after your last `cframed` to see what I mean

Comment: @JosephElcid Ah, now I see. You're right. I'll provide a fix in some time; right now I must leave.

Comment: Next time I will test it ;-)

Comment: @JosephElcid I've updated my answer providing a modified and corrected solution with `framed`.

Answer (score 6):

As Claudio suggested, `tcolorbox` is another possibility. Here you have Gonzalo's second example, adapted to this package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{cframed}[1][blue]
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=#1,colback=white]}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{cframed}
\lipsum[4]
\end{cframed}
\begin{cframed}[red]
\lipsum[4]
\end{cframed}
\begin{cframed}[green]
\lipsum[4]
\end{cframed}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty!  The thicker lines make the colors more vivid!